# Can I connect the ground pin of the wall socket to neutral?

Tags: grounding, socket, neutral

I have leaking currents issues in my apartment. There are some appliances in the apartment that don't have a problem with a wall socket that doesn't have a ground; like, TV, mobile charger, laptop charger, water heater, clothes washer, electric oven and router.

But there are other appliances that have a problem and need grounding to get rid of these leaking currents in the apartment which are; the PC rig power supply and my dish washer, but what is the reason of getting electric shock in my apartment ! I don't know.

The dish washer most the time shock me when I touch its internal metal surface, and my PC power supply is under the stress of leaking currents all the time ! Every time I touch the edges of the case I get an electric shock.

I thought the power supply is faulty, and I bought a new one and the same problem ! Then I learned that power supply need the ground but why exactly, I don't know.

======================================================================

Now it come to the configuration of electrical installation in my country. We now in modern cities, have 3-ph, star connection to the main panel of each apartment. Between each phase is 391V and any phase with neutral is 220V.

I think the neutral is also connected to the earth because in the main panel there's a big black wire that's going down with the 3-ph cables too. But I'm not sure if it's really going to a REAL ground of the building.

## ========================================================================

OK guys I have some new stuff I found inside the apartment :)

Today I did a trick that my colleagues told me to do.

Which is to connect the power strip and measure the voltages between L-GND and N-GND, and the results are interesting !

Without a power strip, that if I connect the DMM to the wall outlet directly then I won't find any voltages between L-GND and N-GND. But when I connect the power strip I find that L-GND gives 103V and N-GND 85V !! Why that ??

There are the photos I took this evening.

I did 2 tests with the DMM. 1 is using only one DMM probe and the other is floating 2 using both DMM probes.

1. First floating test:

This is live because it gives 23V
[image: floating1]

This is of course is neutral
[image: floating2]

2. Voltage from L-GND and N-GND on the power strip:

This should be L-GND because it's higher voltage of 103V

[image: L-GND]

This is N-GND

[image]

This is the power strip from inside:

[image]

Comment: this DOES NOT solve the issue. This may make symptoms go away but if you're getting electric shocks in your apartment you *need* to get an electrician because there is a wiring fault that you *cannot* fix yourself

Comment: Are you in the UK? Is that a UK socket? Are you sure you have 3 phase? And don’t do what you are suggesting - get an electrician because it sounds unsafe at the moment.

Comment: This is called "bootlegging ground" and is a Bad Idea™ for reasons such as i) it will stop tripping GFCIs; ii) any external metal will now have a potential and and iii) if there is no proper earth, then if there is a failure in the neutral between this socket and the panel, then the chassis will now be at line voltage.

Comment: I added a link to my apartment brief explanation.

Comment: But you have not said the country...

Comment: Devices with grounded plugs need the ground, this is no surprise, and even manuals may mention this. They need it for various reasons, for example they might just ground the metal case without any other purpose, or in case of computer power supplies, they have filter capacitors from Live and Neutral to Ground, so connecting those to ungrounded outlets will actually make the filter caps to work as capacitive divider and that will make the computer "ground" to actually be a 110V AC voltage.

Comment: A three pin outlet (hot, neutral, ground) that doesn't have ground wired is **wrong.**  That is the problem to be fixed.  You are proposing a ["bootleg ground,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootleg_ground) which has hazards of its own.  Neither is good.

Comment: @SolarMike Saudi Arabia

Comment: I don't know why I got the down vote to my question ? I tried to be precise as I could. Could anyone tell me what's the problem with my question ? I want actually to get up votes.

Comment: Thanks guys for removing the down vote, this motivates me to feel good about my thread. I have photos I took this morning for our distribution point. But where to add them, in the main thread after editing or as an answer ?

Comment: **Bootlegging the ground connection at the power outlets creates a situation than can kill you or other people.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=connect+ground+to+neutral

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yeah, but it's still a different situation. Because I have 3-ph with neutral.

Comment: But you're not accessing 3-phase there.  You are only working with one phase, therefore you have single-phase just like I do.  The problem is the ground on your socket is not connected to anything.

Comment: Yep, that's right. I don't know how to solve this issue I can't power my PC because of leaking currents that can destroy something or shock a person.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

It turned out that the neutral is grounded. The electricity company is actually grounding the neutral from the distribution room. That's why they are grounding the main building panel.

I bootlegged the neutral to ground and it works fine now.

I actually not considering that bootlegging is a SOLUTION. But according to the fact that the neutral is grounded, then this is a good solution now to get rid of those floating voltages on the house appliances.

Comment: That ground connection is legal and technically correct. it is NOT THE SAME as connecting ground to neutral at the socket. || As shown here, with PROPERLY WIRED SOCKETS (1) If an appliance has dangerous leakage currents to ground then ground-fault-interrupters in the switchboard or sometimes in appliances will trip and save your life. (2) In the event of a Phase to ground fault in an appliance there will be a conductor from fault to switchboard ground with no other load current on it to assist with fuse tripping. (3) If you get an appliance fault where phase connects to neutral in the ...

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your cooperative discussion and your goal to help me, also that's how I know the person that is writing to me is seriously professional ! At least to my standards. So thank you again I really liked this reply by just reading the first lines. But I hope you are not the one that put the negative vote on my answer :)

Comment: `That ground connection is legal and technically correct. it is NOT THE SAME as connecting ground to neutral at the socket` why it's not the same ?! It's absolutely the same, because the whole panel ground is connected to the neutral, so they are taking their ground from the neutral. And I'm doing the same, I'm connecting my ground to the neutral. And now when I measure the voltage between the neutral and the case it's very very low voltage, 45mV !!

Comment: OK. Apparently you do want robust mode.  FWIW no, I did not downvote anything here - but you deserve MANY downvotes. You will not listen. People are wasting their time trying to help you. You are wasting your time even starting to ask questions as you do not listen and do not believe what people who obviously know what they are talking about tell you. || You say " why it's not the same ?!" -> for the reasons I and others have told you again and again and again. You said " ... It's absolutely the same, ..." -> That's calling me a liar and stupid. Read what I and others have said. Consider: ...

Comment: ... all over the world people who wire sockets properly run separate ground wires from power points back to the switch board and do not join them at the socket. According to you the whole world is wasting a whole 33% of their premises wiring needlessly and they are stupid stupid stupid. || Does it seem just likely that they are NOT using all that wire needlessly, that the regulations and standards have a reason for existing and that the whole electrical wiring world , governments, regulatory authorities etc are NOT stupid stupid stupid? || Think about it. Very carefully. || ...

Comment: Note - my aim is to keep you alive, your friends alive and your house unburned. So far I do not seem to be winning :-(. || And again: @R1S8K "Bootlegging the ground" WORKS in the same way that taking the batteries out of a smoke alarm does - it disable a source of annoyance and substitutes a lethal kluge that can kill you or others. || "Makes me feel good" and "is the correct solution" are quite often not the same. || RUN a GROUND WIRE TO THE SOCKET FROM THE SWITCH BOARD. Save your house and your life and your friend's lives. Validate your insurance. Stay alive.

Comment: `According to you the whole world is wasting a whole 33% of their premises wiring needlessly and they are stupid stupid stupid` it's not like that, the thing is that the electrical installation in the building is tight, I can't do much of thing ! The room wiring tube is full of wires, I can't pull anything from the main panel, also the area down the street is tight too with cars parking spaces, it would be difficult to installing grounding, it's not impossible. But calling the building owner and talking with people in the building to pay with me for the costs, they may not accept.

Comment: `OK. Apparently you do want robust mode.` No sir .. no need for that. I'm thinking of removing it, as I haven't also modified the other sockets in the apartment, I only modified one socket for testing, and thinking to remove it today. I don't know what to do with my PSU but anyway it would work without putting its ground to the neutral.

Comment: `That's calling me a liar and stupid` nope absolutely not !! I would get my self out of this forum rather than calling anyone like this, I absolutely respect you, and I'm respecting the discussion with you. If I don't care for arguing with you then I would just leave the thread as is and that's it. Anyway, I did not downvote anything here ok thanks, maybe someone didn't like our electricity company installation :)

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time sir with this discussion, I could save your and others time and find another solution. Anyway removing that wire would be a step a way of potential problems for now :)

Comment: Time not wasted if you learn something :-). Others have suggested various ways of addressing the problem. An isolating transformer is one such.

Comment: You know posting in forums is one of the best things in my life. It allows me to deal with smart people, educative, supportive and just have a good sense in life. Sometimes it's hard to deal with engineers because they learned the standard rules of doing any application. And if I asked or suggested something that is rather not practical or not suitable, it could be annoying for them, but anyway thank you so much.

Comment: Jesus christ this is uniquely stupid.

Comment: @Alexander What is stupid exactly ?

Comment: @R1S8K Watching you too talk past each other. It recovered at the end, which I'm glad to see, but reading the first part is hard lol

Comment: Do you mean my arguing with `Russell McMahon`? That I was arguing with him about a wrong action ? Then it recovered by that I decided to undo the fix action ? Anyway,  I don't know what you mean by `talk past each other`, `at the end`, `first part` is that all about my main post of later discussion ?

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE - OCTOBER 26th 2019.

The OP has now connected the neutral to ground at the power socket.
This is against **all** advice from **all** people commenting.
He is completely ignoring the advice supplied by everyone.
He is wasting their time.

**People who do what this guy has done this will kill themselves and their friends.**

**Don't be like this guy.**

**_____________________________________**

Doing what you suggest may be fatal.
Dying will mean you do not have the problem any more but is not the best solution.
Ground and Neutral are NOT identical in functionality and need to be isolated from each other in use (despite being connected at the switchboard).

> There are some appliances in the apartment that don't have a problem with a wall socket that doesn't have a ground; ... But there are other appliances that have a problem and need grounding to get rid of these leaking currents

If, as you appear to be saying, the problem occurs with only some appliances only when a power outlet without ground is used then the correct solution is to use outlets which DO have a correct ground connection.

The reason that the problem exists is probably due to noise reduction capacitors in the input circuitry to the appliances concerned. There are two "Y" capacitors connected between ground and Phase & Neutral. When the ground lead is correctly connected the two capacitors 'carry noise currents to ground'. But, when the ground connection is floating the two capacitors form a voltage divider between phase and neutral, with the appliance chassis ground at the midpoint between the two capacitors - forming a high impedance connection at about half supply voltage. This then causes electric shocks between the appliance body at about Vmains/2 and a user connecting between boy and ground (via shoes or hands or ...) will feel a shock. This is usually unpleasant but nowhere near as severe as a full mains to ground shock. If the shock you feel is more a highly unpleasant bite than a muscle spasming grabbing blow then you are probably experiencing a Y capacitor shock.
**Use a grounded outlet!**

Comment: Thank you so much I really liked your answer, that's is pretty much the reason for the problems I have. The noise capacitors .. I really liked that part of the your explanation. They should be the reason. The shocks are unpleasant, but also dangerous for my PC parts, I lost a GPU that costed me $400! I got a new one and I don't want to lose it again ! it's also for $470.

Comment: I think the best solution is to ask our electricity company, and they would tell me if the neutral is grounded at the main district power distribution room.

Comment: @R1S8K The best solution is 1. to use an outlet with a grounded earth pin. 2. To understand the probable reason that you get a shock with a completely properly working appliance when there is no ground connection - as I described.  || Ground and Neutral are often joined at the switch board. This produces a different result than joining them at the socket. The latter disables modern protection equipment (GFI / ELCB / ...) and adds a hazard

Comment: OK, so I only have the chance that bootlegging should work only is they are joined at the switch board of the district. OK, I got it .. so if it's not !! Then joining them at the socket would be the hazardous solution. Thank you so much. Now I know what to do, is to know if the neutral is **grounded at the district distribution room or not ??**

Comment: @R1S8K  NO!. No no no. || You need to read my answer more more more carefully. | The appliances concerned are designed to work with a ground on their ground pin. THEY do not care whether they get it by correct or incorrect means. Correct means is via an independent ground lead to the switchboard.  The bootlegging works by providing a ground to the appliance ground circuit BUT in the process it disables GFI/ELCB protection (which you hopefully have got in your modern switchboard.) || YOU NEED OUTLETS WITH GROUND CONNECTIONS. ||

Comment: I update the post ..

Comment: @R1S8K  Vital question: Does your installation have ELCBS/GFIs/ earth leak trip breakers or same thing by some other name? || If yes then connecting ground pin of socket to neutral pin of socket will disable these. They are superb life protection systems.

Comment: @R1S8K  Your enthusiastic approach is appreciated and commendable - BUT you MUST listen. You INSIST on not reading what I or others say properly. You will kill yourself or someone else in the end. 1. If the "shocks" you receive are unpleasant but not brutally grabbing and clearly life threatening **THEN** READ MY ANSWER - The part that starts "The reason that the problem exists ..." explains the reason that the problem exists. This IS the reason that the problem exists.

Comment: @R1S8K   Appliances that give you nasty but not life threatening shocks when you touch them have noise filter capacitors in then that float the appliance body at about half supply. 

The proper way to cure this is to ground them via the socket using a ground lead that runs from socket to the distribution board. The outley ground lead should connect to an eartj busbar in the distribution board. This earth busbar MAY to the neutral bus bar that the neutrals feed from AT THE SWITCHBOARD but not elsewhere in the installation.

Comment: @R1S8K You keep asking and asking and asking BUT you will not listen to the answers. Your outley MUST have a ground lead of its own IF you want to be safe and IF you want to use appliances with noise filter capacitors without receiving shocks. || The plugboard demonstration is the same effect BUT the capacitors here are your body to ground or the meter leads to ground or the capacitive connection of the wiring in the plug box. You 1st photo **PROVES** this.  You should not expect a metter to read with one lead open circuit (OC) and the fact that it does should show you that something ...

Comment: @R1S8K you do not understand is happening. The current is flowing via capacitive coupling via the test lead and your body to ground. This is the same as the capacitors that are causing the shocks but they have higher capacitance so more current flows. Your photos does not show the input end of the plug box internals. It should. There may be filter caps there or it maybe just capacitance between the wiring runs. Connecting P-gnd you see coupling via the N-GND cap. Connecting N-gnd you see the midpoint of the C_PG and C_NG caps so the voltage is lower.

Comment: @R1S8K USE A GROUNDED OUTLET. RUN A GND WIRE TO SWITCHBOARD IF NECESSARY. OR USE AN ISOLATING TRANSFORMER.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the comments. I'm so thankful for all your multiple comments. Just I want you to be sure that I'm honored to read your comments :)

Comment: check my answer, it turned out that the building panel is grounded, so I bootlegged the neutral to ground. Now I think the situation has lower risk than before ! Do you agree with me ?

Comment: @R1S8K **Death is too good for some people - apparently you wish to share it with others :-(. || You have completely ignored everything that everyone has told you. You have failed to report on the basic tests suggested that would prove the fault is not what you think. You have taken the most lethally dangerous option. Killing yourself or someone else is now more likely. Does that sound lower risk to you?**

Comment: No !! But as the picture I uploaded to the answer, the neutral is grounded. It's a STAR connection from the main transformer and the neutral is grounded from the electricity company. Isn't that enough at least to suppress those floating voltages ? The neutral is very low voltage and is maximum 0.5 to 1.5 volts.

Comment: @R1S8K To quote "zerowing" / "All your base are belong to us": " You have no chance to survive, make your time. Ha ha ha ha" -> except, here, nobody is laughing. You have been told many many many many times by many many people that what you have now done is lethally dangerous, stupid, non-standard, and may kill you or somebody else (or both). You have ignored this advice consistently and just kept on insisting on doing it your way. The correct way is listed in my and other answers. || If  somebody dies you may be legally guilty of manslaughter. I understand that you are in Saudi Arabia :-(.

Comment: OK, then I have to find a better solution for this situation. It's not comfortable to me. I'm really not ignoring you or anybody else .. it's just the guys in my department that one of them worked in electricity company and then joined us at the college told me to connect it to the metal casing of the socket !! Good think that there are no screws exposed, there's a plastic cover for the whole socket. But I didn't like that solution and it even didn't work as I tried that. The other guy told me just to bootleg the ground as other people have done it and that's it.

Comment: I've done it but I don't know if it's really safe as the mains neutral is grounded and our configuration is TN-S that the neutral is grounded. I watched a video last night and to be sure that your grounding is good the voltage from the neutral to ground shouldn't exceed 1.5V and mine is 1V so that's why I knew that it's ok.

Comment: @R1S8K [<gentle_mode>] :-). You ARE ignoring us, effectively, even if you are reading what we say. We all (or most ) knew that connecting neutral to ground AT the socket would cure the symptoms. That is not the issue. The issue is that you have equipment which almost certainly NOT faulty but which is giving you MINOR & non-dangerous electric shocks BECAUSE it is designed to work with correctly wired power outlets. Rather than correctly wire the power outlets or take other solutions offered you have chosen a dangerous kluge which removes the immediate symptoms but renders your system lethally..

Comment: ... dangerous in the event of a major fault. Having a SEPERATE ground wire from socket to switchboard is part of the intended system design. Instead, joining them at the socket is not correct. No amount of "but it eliminates the small non-dangerous shocks when I do this dangerous kluge" will make it safe sensible or correct.

Comment: Thanks for the [<gentle_mode>] :) .. I waited for couple days to test the stuff I'm working on. I tested if there are shock or floating voltages. But thankfully things are alright. `The issue is that you have equipment which almost certainly NOT faulty but which is giving you MINOR & non-dangerous electric shocks BECAUSE it is designed to work with correctly wired power outlets.` Yep, that's right but the shocks are at +100V but that could damage things; like, a computer that is stressed at floating 100V could damage my stuff, I lost my $400 GTX 780 classified because of this problem.

Comment: ` No amount of "but it eliminates the small non-dangerous shocks when I do this dangerous kluge" will make it safe sensible or correct` I won't say it's correct or safe, but our neutral is grounded. That's why I feel a little bit good about this. And we are lucky that the electricity company is grounding the neutral according to TN-S system configuration. If it's not as I live with some of the old electric wiring that doesn't have a ground wiring or the neutral isn't grounded, I would say that, it would be already dangerous and totally wrong and lethal.

Comment: @R1S8K  [<less gentle mode>] The neutral is meant to be grounded AT THE SWITCHBOARD. NOT at the outlets. The two locations are not identical electrically, even though this is not obvious to you. You are not listening to what you have been told repeatedly, and also you are not listening to what you have been told repeatedly, AND in addition you are not listening to what you have been told repeatedly. Neutral and ground are joined at the switchboard. Neutral and ground are NOT intended to be joined at the outlet. What you have done removes a key part of the protection system.  SO ...

Comment: @R1S8K  ... When your premises catch fire and/or you die and/or you kill somebody else then it will be your fault. Your insurance may not be valid (and shouldn't be as you have performed an illegal, lethally dangerous and stupid act), and if it is not your premises they may sue you (if you are still alive). || AND You DO have a system that does not have a socket ground, as you have demonstrated. Somebody has illegally dangerously and stupidly wired your premises "not according to code" and you are adding to their criminal stupidity. || [Pause] If I'm not this robust I'm not going to get ...

Comment: @R1S8K ... through to you. Am I ? :-( :-). || I and all the others are trying to help here. Try and listen. Your wiring is BAD. You have added a kluge which removes an annoyance but instead adds lethal danger. You need to get it fixed properly. || If I understand your criminal justice system correctly I would not want to be playing with it the way you are :-(. |||| Should I try [<much more robust mode>] ?

Answer (score 4):

In an improperly wired electrical outlet, yes this might help (depending on the configuration). But you should not connect ground to neutral. Neutral is for carrying return currents and can develop a voltage on it, it should not be shorted to ground. If you do short it to ground, you have a potential for a safety hazard as the chassis of the device your plugging into the wall could have a potential on it. During a fault the device chassis could also gain an unsafe potential on it.

The best thing to do would be to have the wiring fixed to the appropriate IEC standards.

Comment: Yep .. you're right! I discovered other issues this evening!

Comment: I update the post ..

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is your ground terminal in your socket  is not connected

You need to do one of these:

- assure that your local main panel has a grounding electrode actually going to earth, and then, you need to run an electrical wire from the socket in the wall to your main panel.
- Install an RCD (also called GFCI) device to protect this circuit, however this will be a waste of time since it will simply trip the next time you get shocked.
- Install an isolation transformer, and ground it.

I get where you don't want to do anything like this, or anything at all.  That means you will continue to get shocks, and the shocks will have a chance of killing you, or family, or guests. If you are the responsible householder, this could result in lawsuits or even your imprisonment *since you were aware of the problem and did not fix it*.

---

The other problem is, that since you are keen on not fixing this, you are using your brain to create *rationalizations* as to why you should not need to fix it.  These are lies.  You need to fix it.

---

Do not connect neutral to ground at the socket. This is dangerous, and will also defeat the protection of an RCD device. Ground is only connected to neutral in your main panel.

**Some believe that if a wire is grounded in *one* place, then that wire is grounded everywhere**.  No. That is absolutely not true.  If you doubt that, then think about this: why on earth would  all the first-world nations spend 50% more copper putting a separate ground wire in every cable?  If neutral was as good as ground, *why run ground?*

Location matters.  The neutral being grounded in the service panel (if that's even true) doesn't buy you anything out on the branch circuits.

So yeah, the transformer presumably has an Ufer ground going into the transformer pad, and that ground ties to the supply neutral there.  This is an **equipotential bond** designed to assure the transformer secondary voltages are within 240V of ground.

However, that is of limited help in the residence - it needs its own ground grounding out the panel.  That's because neutral service wires do in fact fail.  I had one earlier this year, in fact.  **If you had been relying on the neutral wire to obtain ground from the transformer's equipotential bond, your ground voltages could be floating at *anything***.  That could be cataclysmic, if the transformer's primary is leaking even a little.

Your own house's panel needs its own grounding electrode system (ground rods or Ufer).

So, your main panel in the home also has one neutral-ground equipotential bond, again for a variety of purposes but it also backstops the transformer's ground.  **This ground bond is only useful inside the panel**.  If you want ground somewhere else, you need to bring it there.

Now you notice that your panel is *not* set up as a neutral bar, a ground bar, and an obvous neutral-ground equipotential bond that you can point to.  The N-G bond is implemented just by spamming everything onto the same bar. That's perfectly legal, but it's a shame, really; I prefer neutral and ground separate with a distinct equipotential bond that I can clamp an ammeter around to measure leakage.

Out at the outlets we need a way to get ground to them.  Neutral is not the right way, because again, the neutral wire could fail (common failure) and then **you're electrifying every ground in the circuit**.

If your house doesn't has grounds (remember: metal conduit is usually a valid ground path), then you can retrofit the ground wires.  You can't normally just add a single wire to a circuit, but ground is special.

Comment: I update the post ..

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not connect ground to neutral at the outlet.

Worse yet, **your breaker box is lacking a ground so there is no easy way to fix this**. There should be a fifth (green) wire coming into your breaker box. Without a ground, you can never fix this in your apartment, it needs to be fixed at the distribution point further back. The ground should be distributed separately to the outlets, it should never carry current.

This is the best diagram that I can find. Unfortunately, it doesn't show the ground. But, it does explain the phases better than your diagram.

[image]
https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/transformers-phase-converters-and-vfd/need-design-information-440v-3ph-220v-1ph-out-319025/a.jpg

Note that I have never seen 3-phase to 1-phase distribution in a residence, but it is used in factories in the US (at roughly half the voltages shown in the diagram, 208V/120V). The neutral is connected to earth ground at one point, normally where the power enters the building, it should never be connected anywhere else.

Comment: Information only: US outlets are usually +/180 degrees separated as two 1/2 windings on a transformer. What he describes is true 3 phase with 230 VAC phase to neutral and 400V phase to phase - which is what we have in Newzealand. Most hones only have 1 phase supplied. Mine has two as it long ago had 3 phase supply and this was dropped back to 2 phase when the plastic moulding shop in the backyard was emoved - two owners before I bought the house.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. But what if the neutral is grounded at the distribution point?

Comment: The neutral probably is grounded at one point, where the output of the transformer enters the building.

Comment: You got that from the pictures I added, right ? Because you maybe thought that I'm getting the apartment electricity from some poor distribution system? So you think the neutral is grounded, right? I'm pretty sure that bootlegging the ground would work because one of my friends did it and it's working fine with him in the same city. I posted this thread to learn something of countries and how things are going. But also at the same time I wanted to know that if electricity companies actually ground the neutral at distribution points.

Comment: @R1S8K "Bootlegging the ground"  **WORKS** in the same way that taking the batteries out of a smoke alarm does - it disable a source of annoyance and substitutes a lethal kluge that can kill you or others. || "Makes me feel good" and "is the correct solution" are quite often not the same.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yep, I really like the smoke alarm example, I got the idea very similarly. OK, so bootlegging could work but is **FOR SURE** lethal at any chance of cutting the power and the ground is the available path for current that is the real danger. But what if the neutral is grounded from the distribution point?

Comment: *The neutral probably is grounded at one point, where the output of the transformer enters the building. -- You got that from the pictures I added, right?* No, I don't see the neutral connection in the pictures, just the metal case being tied to earth.

Comment: When your life is at stake, you want multiple layers of safety. Assuming that the neutral is grounded at the distribution point (it probably is), if you connect the safety ground to the neutral at the outlet, you only have one layer of safety. If the neutral becomes hot for whatever reason, your safety ground is now hot.

Comment: @Mattman944 Yep, "The neutral probably is grounded at one point" it could be but I'm not doing anything until I'm sure of asking the company and if possible getting a formal employee of the electric company to visit my apartment.

Comment: @Mattman944 "you only have one layer of safety" You mean that if I have a **real** ground then I have more than one layer of safety, right?

Comment: I update the post ..